# MongoDB Randomly Aggregate Documents (Unique Results)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've read that one can use `db.collection.aggregate` with `$sample` to get random documents from a collection. But I've also read that the $sample is NOT 100% reliable, therefore, I wrote this query:

```
db.blog.aggregate(
   {"$sample": { "size": 100 } }, 
   {"$group": { "_id" : "$post_id", "post" : { "$push" : "$$ROOT" }}}
)
```

Yes, I am attempting to group by, but the issue is that in a loop it becomes more complicated then it should i.e. when querying the results from MongoDB.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I want to know, is grouping necessary to get unique results out, or is there a better way of doing this. It does NOT make sense to have to the $group for aggregate to return me several random documents from the MongoDB that are unique and not duplicates.

YES, I set the ID to INDEX unique in the actual collection.

Comment: can you clarify what exactly are you asking? whats the problem with current query results? what do you want them to be?

Comment: @tomslabbaert, thx for your reply. I want the aggregate to give me unique results in return. I read somewhere that it can return duplicates, when using `$sample`. In addition, I also want to know if there is a better why than being forced to use `$group`.

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. Can you please explain bit more.

Comment: @Ashh, see my latest EDIT, thanks!

Comment: With which field do you need unique documents? If postId is already set to unique the you do not need to use group here. And if you want random documents then sample will do the job

Comment: Thanks! But will they be unique, because I read somewhere that $sample does return duplicates, or this does not apply if the field is already unique in the original collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) over the post_id field than there is no need of group operation after sampling.

Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#faq-developers-isolate-cursors

Comment: Is there any reason why post_id can't be the _id field? If you can replace _id (if currently it is autogenerated with no info) value with post_id then basically you don;t need to add index as well.

Comment: @John Smith Is there any doubt still pending around this question?

Comment: Need to further investigate.

Comment: Investigate what? Share your doubts please.

Comment: I haven't had time to test your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets begin in clarifying the $sample unique-ness issue as its not as straight forward as you might think.

First lets see the $sample conditions as specified in the docs:

> 1. $sample is the first stage of the pipeline
> 2. N is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection
> 3. The collection contains more than 100 documents

If these conditions are not met mongo will perform a collection scan with sort and pick random documents (in this case no duplicates will occur).

Assuming these conditions ARE met then duplicate ids can occur by something called [cursor isolation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-isolation).
This can only happen if you got update/delete operations on the collection that might 'fuck with' the indexing of it.

So assuming you're in this final case and your collection is being updated while you're querying it then grouping is your best shot if you want to ensure 100% that no dups will be returned. (with that said grouping on 100 documents is quite a small overhead to be worried about ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 100 was a sample I posted here, what would you say about 5 000?